# Returning property "name" inside an object without know the "name"

Tags: javascript, object, boolean

Alright, this is probably a really stupid question, but I must ask. I have an object inside an object:

```
var user = {
    playlist: "abcd1234",
    role: {
      basic: true,
    }
};
```

I know I can access the role by:

```
user.role
```

which will return {basic: true} in the console. My question is how could I return just "basic" if I didn't know what was inside role?

I am working on a project where I am getting multiple objects (of users) and need to put their roles into a select field. I was hoping just to get "basic" (for example) to look a little nicer as an option for the user to select rather than basic = true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is the name of the property inside `user.role`, [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) is probably what you want. It returns in an array all of an object's property names (also known as "keys").

```js
var user = {
    playlist: "abcd1234",
    role: {
      basic: true,
    }
};

let roles = Object.keys(user.role);
console.log(roles); // ["basic"]
```

But if you want only the roles that are `true`, that requires some filtering:

```js
var user = {
    playlist: "abcd1234",
    role: {
      basic: true,
      admin: false,
      free: true
    }
};

const reduceTrues = (acc, [key, val]) => {
  if (val === true) { acc.push(key); }
  return acc;
}
const trueRoles = Object.entries(user.role).reduce(reduceTrues, []);
console.log(trueRoles);
// [ 'basic', 'free' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.keys()` method like this

```js
var user = {
  playlist: "abcd1234",
  role: {
    basic: true,
  }
}
const role = Object.keys(user.role)
console.log(role) // ["basic"]
console.log(user.role[role]) // true
```

Full documentation in MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<script>
var user = {
    playlist: "abcd1234",
    role: {
      basic: true,
      admin: false,
      free: false
    }
};


for(role in user.role){
    if(user.role[role]){
        console.log(role);
    }
}
</script>
</html>
```

So you are essentially iterating over unknown properties in the `user.role` object. For every `role` in `user.role`, check if it is true with `user.role[role]` - the `[role]` is the variable name we are not aware of - then i just `console.log` if it is true, you can run other logic if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the properties of an object you can simple use

```
var user = {
    playlist: "abcd1234",
    role: {
      basic: true,
    }
};
var roles=Object.keys(user.role);
console.log(roles);
```

Answer (score -2):

If you have several roles, I suggest you make the roles as a comma separated list and then split using the `String.split()` method.

For example:

```
var user = { playlist: "abcd1234", role: "basic, pro, other" };

var roles = user.role.split(",");
//You now have an array of roles
```

But in case you have just 1 role, simply set it as a string as in

```
    var user = { playlist: "abcd1234", role: "basic" };

//You can check if role is empty by a simple if statement

if(user.role != null && user.role != undefined && user.role != "")
console.log("user role is "+user.role);
```